# Listen to a service property inside of index.html

Tags: html, angular, typescript

On every reload I'm fetching data from the database. To prevent user's from seeing the app without the data being loaded, I have a promise with a resolve.

What I want is an animation to be executed right before it's being resolved - my approach is to change a property inside of the `AppInitService` and as soon it's f.e. true, the angular browser animation shall be executed.

The animations takes place in index.html inside of `<app-root>...</app-root>`, since its content is being displayed on app init. **How do I listen (subscribe) to the `AppInitService`'s property inside of index.html?** Is there a .ts file allocated to index.html?

Is there a different approach?

AppInitService:

```
Init(): Promise<any> {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  this.db.collection('entries').valueChanges()
    .subscribe(val => {
      this.casesService.data = val;
      resolve(true);
    });
});}
```

app.module.ts:

```
export function initializeApp1(appInitService: AppInitService) {
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return appInitService.Init();
  };
}

providers: [
   AppInitService,
   { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeApp1, deps: [AppInitService], multi: true }
],
```

Comment: Placing a loading indicator, image, gif,  css controlled anim etc. between `<app-root>` tags why not an option?

Comment: @robert That's what I have so far - but I want to start the animation just when the app is finished fetching the data and then delay the resolve by the duration x of the animation.

Answer (score 2):

I created an animated logo for my website that is shown before the Angular application has been started. The logo persists until the router outlet is activated, but you can use any logic as the trigger you want.

You can see the logo by visiting the website (shameless self promotion)

https://reactgular.com/

You might have to refresh the page to see it. It appears for a very short amount of time.

The app component removes the logo here:

https://github.com/reactgular/website/blob/ebd39dda032eb2bb77b9f6ae77354445a6c90cfa/src/app/main/body/body.component.ts#L54

The `index.html` page displays the logo here:

https://github.com/reactgular/website/blob/ebd39dda032eb2bb77b9f6ae77354445a6c90cfa/src/index.html#L75

It's important **not** to add the logo inside your Angular bootstrap component. The logo will be immediately removed when Angular starts, but you want it to be delayed. So you show it outside of Angular and have to manually remove it later.

Here is a copy of the `index.html` file that can be re-used. You are welcome to use the HTML, but please use a different logo.

https://github.com/reactgular/media/blob/master/src/index.html

Comment: This question might be dumb, but how did you manage to connect `index.html` and `body.component.ts`?

Comment: @Tim they aren't connected. The body component just queries the DOM and removes the logo element. I wait for the router outlet to activate with a route, by that time I assume everything is ready.

Comment: So you aren't working with `<app-root>` at all? How do I know whether the data has successfully been fetched, since I don't have a promise/resolve in your version.

Comment: @Tim I think you're using an `APP_INITIALIZER` so you can remove the logo during the `OnInit()` of the app component, because the initializer has finished already. Otherwise, you could use a shared service and listen for a promise or something like that.

Comment: Yes you're right. But how can I use a service inside of index.html?

Comment: @Tim you don't need to do anything inside the `index.html` file. You just show a logo as part of the HTML, and then remove it later when the app is ready.

Comment: @Reactgular +1 shameless self promotion :-)

Comment: "It's important not to add the logo inside your Angular bootstrap component." - I don't get this. Can you elaborate please

Comment: @robert if you do this `<app-root><span id="logo">XXX</span></app-root>` the `#logo` is removed from the DOM immediately by Angular. The bootstrap component can not have content from the `index.html`.

Comment: @Reactgular Yes, that's right and with APP_INITIALIZER you can delay that removal until you receive startup data from your backend, right?

Comment: @robert right, the logo can be positioned absolute so that the app can be drawn and the logo is overtop of everything. I think that's how I do it. I can't remember, but basically you've lazy removing it at someone when you know everything is ready.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an animation to be executed when app is loading, just write your own `styles` in head in index.html. You should write html for animation between `<app-root>Loading....</app-root>` because it will be replaced once the content is ready and gets rendered.

On the other hand, if you want to have some sort of loader inside your application, you should make "loader component" and have service that "shows/hide" that loader.